# Changing scene on collision - cannot remove-scene() perspective.lua: attempt to compare nil with number

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to change scene when there is a collision with an object. Just for information, when i use a listener on a button, it works well ! The scene est cleaned and there is no problem with "physics" anymore.

> scene : CH1-SAH-A01

```
    function onCollision(event)
        if (event.phase=="began") then
            if (event.object1.myName=="hero" and event.object2.myName=="start_point") then              
                composer.gotoScene("CH1-SPR-A01", "fade", 500)
            end
        elseif (event.phase=="ended") then
            if (event.object1.myName=="hero" and event.object2.myName=="ground") then   
            end
         end
    end
```

and i start physics here :

```
function scene:show( event )

local sceneGroup = self.view
local phase = event.phase

if ( phase == "will" ) then
      -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
    camera:setBounds(display.contentWidth/2,4200-display.contentWidth*0.5,display.contentHeight-1500,-220)
    camera.damping=1
    physics.start()
    camera:track()
    setHeroPropreties()
```

Then, when the scene is left :

```
function scene:hide( event )
  local sceneGroup = self.view
  local phase = event.phase    
   if ( phase == "will" ) then        
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function() physics.stop();end )
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", ShowCharacters)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision)
    slideOffSensor:removeEventListener( "touch", handleSlideOff )
    composer.removeScene("CH1-SAH-A01")
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then          

   end
end
```

and the destroy function is :

```
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local camera = self.view
    package.loaded[physics] = nil
    physics = nil
end
```

I tried to add a timer in the function physics.stop() in vain. After the collision, there are some "errors" in the virtual console monitor :

I don't use transition.to() in my current and destination scene, and i've this error :

> ERROR: Cannot translate an object before collision is resolved

I added a timer in the physics.addbody to my "hero" and start_point (in the destination scene), and still have this error :

> ERROR: physics.addBody() cannot be called when the world is locked and
>   in the middle of number crunching, such as during a collision event

Any advice ?

Comment: What line is the lua error thrown. It just means that a value that is `nil` is being compared to something that's a number (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In corona you can't change anything about the objects that are involved with the collision until the collision is over. In addition you can't call physics.stop() while the collision is ongoing. You need to use a flag or a delay with timer.performWithDelay () until the collision is over before you change scene.

This is covered in the "important" section in this link:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html